# Append a item to an array that is inside a object with useState Hook

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I need to append new values to an array that is inside a `useState` hook, here is the interface and hook:

```js
interface ObjetoAdicionaItem {
    tipo: string;
    nome: string;
    borda: string;
    pratos: number;
    observacao: string;
    quantidade: [{
        pronome: string;
        quantidadeSabor: number;
    }];
}
```

Here is the hook:

```
const [arrayItens, setArrayItens] = useState<ObjetoAdicionaItem>();
const [sabores, setSabores] = useState<DadosSabor[]>([]);
```

The problem is when I try to append new items to the array `quantidade`;

Sample code:

```js
sabores = [{
    quantidadeSabor: 1,
    pronome: "foo",
    preco: "bar",
    checked: false
  },
  {
    quantidadeSabor: 2
    pronome: "foo2",
    preco: "bar",
    checked: false
  }
]

let nome = sessionStorage.getItem("pronomeAtualSabor") || "";
sabores.map(item => {
  if (item.quantidadeSabor !== 0 && item.quantidadeSabor !== undefined) {
    setArrayItens({
      borda: bordaAtual,
      nome: nome,
      observacao: observacao,
      pratos: quantidadePratos,
      tipo: "sabor",
      quantidade: [{ ...arrayItens ? .quantidade,
        pronome : item.pronome,
        quantidadeSabor: item.quantidadeSabor
      }]
    });
  }
})
```

expected output:

```
arrayItens: {
    borda: 'foo',
    nome: "bar",
    observacao: "...",
    pratos: 5,
    tipo: "sabor", 
    quantidade: [
        {
            pronome: "foo",
            quantidadeSabor: 1
        },
        {
            pronome: "foo2",
            quantidadeSabor: 2
        }
    ]   
}
```

Comment: `arrayItens` is initially `undefined` is this intentional? Is it supposed to be an array? Please add some sample data and expected outcome

Comment: arrayItens will be filled in the "sabores.map(...)", no, it's not supposed to be an array, but, to have an array inside it. I will edit with the samples

Comment: `map()` is not a method for filing something, maybe you want `forEach()` but it looks like you'll be overwriting `setArrayItens` every time the condition is met. It is not clear what you want...

Comment: I updated with the sample code, i expect it will be better to understand what I want.

Comment: It's not the root problem, but your interface for ObjetoAdicionaItem  is defining `quantidade` as a 1-element tuple instead of as an array, so the type claims that it always contains exactly 1 element. Move the `[` to the end of the object, rather than surrounding the object with brackets: `quantidade: { pronome: ... }[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your code should be something like this:

```
setArrayItens((prevArrayItens) => ({
  ...prevArrayItens,
  quantidade: sabores.map(({pronome, quantidadeSabor}) => quantidadeSabor && {
    pronome,
    quantidadeSabor
 })
})
```

---

```js
const sabores = [{
    quantidadeSabor: 1,
    pronome: "foo",
    preco: "bar",
    checked: false
  },
  {
    quantidadeSabor: 2,
    pronome: "foo2",
    preco: "bar",
    checked: false
  }
]

const result = sabores.map(({
  pronome,
  quantidadeSabor
}) => quantidadeSabor && {
  pronome,
  quantidadeSabor
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I want. I'll try to explain: I have an object with some properties, and an array of objects inside that first object. I want to fill the first properties only once and append other values to that array of objects that is inside the first object.

Comment: @MuriloDagustin isn't that what the commented code doing? The demo is only showing correct value of `quantidade` property.

Comment: The demo can't run things like `setArrayItens` without React and everything else around it

Comment: I tried, but now i get this error: 
```
Type '(0 | { pronome: string; quantidadeSabor: number; } | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type '[{ pronome: string; quantidadeSabor: number; }]'.
  Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2322)
```

Comment: @MuriloDagustin this is a typescript error, the solution is mentioned in the comments of your question by "Stephen Jennings"

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I updated the interface as Stephen mentioned, but, it still giving me an error. 


Type '(0 | { pronome: string; quantidadeSabor: number; } | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type '{ pronome: string; quantidadeSabor: number; }[]'.
  Type '0 | { pronome: string; quantidadeSabor: number; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ pronome: string; quantidadeSabor: number; }'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ pronome: string; quantidadeSabor: number; }'.ts(2322)